# Automatic Adding of libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to change some settings in VS2015 to always include a certain library?

Like for example the stl libraries are always on the path `<chrono> <thread>` can be found by the compiler without additional settings.

I have some basic libraries that I always use for projects, additions to the string library and some file io stuff for example. I have a project for each library where I maintain these functions and templates to create new versions of the .lib files.

However every time I am making a new project, I have to do the same riddle over and over again of adding the external libraries to the project. Is there anyway I can automate this? Tell visual studio that there are some default libs?

Comment: pre compiler header and `pragma lib` may help.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you elaborate on that?

Comment: But better is [Sharing reusable property configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#bkmkPropertySheets)

Comment: Instead of manually adding a property sheet to each new project you can also create a new project template that automatically include the property sheets you want (also, that way can make x64 the default instead of having to remove Win32 each and every time)

Comment: These are solution based aren't they. I am using different configurations to build 32 or 64bit versions of my lib or to create a debug run to test. These cannot be used cross solution can they?

Comment: @PeterT That is already an improvement. This basically creates the settings for me, great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share property sheets between projects. It's a great way to share common properties.

I use a system with six property sheets: four for compile modes (32-bits/64-bits, and release/debug), and two for system customisation (basically, fixed paths). The first set of four can be checked into version control; the last two are dependent on where your directory is located and as such are different on each machine. So in the end each compile mode has two additional sheets:

```
COMPILE MODE     PROPERTY SHEET                   PATHS
32-bit debug     properties for 32-bits debug     paths for 32-bits
32-bit release   properties for 32-bits release   paths for 32-bits
64-bit debug     properties for 64-bits debug     paths for 64-bits
64-bit release   properties for 64-bits release   paths for 64-bits
```

Property sheets are found in the property manager (in VS2015 community that's under "view" / "property manager"; in different Visual Studio versions it tends to move around a bit). In the property manager you can expand your project (this shows the compile modes), and then expand a compile mode to see the attached property sheets. If you right-click on a compile mode you can add new or existing property sheets.

You can select multiple projects at the same time and add a property sheet to all of them simultaneously. To edit properties *in a specific property sheet*, select that sheet first.

The only annoying thing is that I always find myself going through the project (after creating it) and removing all the properties that Microsoft already thoughtfully set on the project itself (i.e. selecting them all and choosing "inherit"). That's annoying, but once you've set it up you can easily change properties over all your projects by simply editing the right sheet.

Comment: I have kinda the same settings, however these are solution dependant arent they. If I create a new solution I have to manually make those property sheets again. Or am I missing something

Comment: It's entirely up you how you want to organize them. They can be solution-dependent, but if you prefer sharing them across many solutions there's nobody stopping you.

Comment: How, where do I find these property sheets and how can I load them in new solutions.

Comment: Added some extra clarification on how to use.